# How to extract PDF links that contain spaces from a cell using regextract in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to extract .pdf links from a string in column A1:A.

Below are sample .pdf links. The issue is that they contain spaces which I would like to replace with %20. That I am able to do.

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
https://example.com/api/viewdocs/Documents/167195398373-029-TEST - ONE (SECTION A) Random Document.pdf 
https://example.com/api/viewdocs/Documents/16784456078-EXAMPLE DOCUMENT NOV 2022 - Another.pdf
```

The number of links could be 2, could be 10, could be anything. So I need to extract all matches.

AND

Wrap the links to form a html link element. From the above example, the result in column B would be also with spaces removed:

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
<a href="https://example.com/api/viewdocs/Documents/167195398373-029-TEST%20-%20ONE%20(SECTION%20A)%20Random%20Document.pdf">Document 1</a> 
<a href="https://example.com/api/viewdocs/Documents/16784456078-EXAMPLE%20DOCUMENT%20NOV%202022%20-%20Another.pdf">Document 2</a>
```

What I have tried:
I am only able to extract a single link. I have tried to get all of them but it's not possible with my formula which needs readjusting. I also removed spaces from the link to form a clickable link.

My formula:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "https://.*?\.pdf")`

Then for removing spaces:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "https://.*?\.pdf")," ","%20"))`

Please note that the text inside the first column is a mixture of the links and other text so we need to only get the text between `https` AND `.pdf` for any number of links.

Please help.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your question, which are the sample input and output values you expected?

Comment: I have managed a bit with ```=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"https.*.pdf")),"https","<a href=""https"),".pdf",".pdf"">DOCUMENT</a>"))``` I don't know if it's possible to have the link text change to DOCUMENT 1 OR DOCUMENT 2 etc depending on number of documents but so far this is close to what I needed. Just some tweaking left.

Comment: @Tanaike I updated the question and your English is better than mine so don't worry.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, the values of "SAMPLE INPUT" is put into one cell? And, you want to convert it to "SAMPLE OUTPUT" in one cell?

Comment: Sample input is in A1 and output in B1. For the sample input, it has the links I posted there but it also has other text which is mixed with the links. But I am only interested in the text between "https" and ".pdf". The formula I posted is working. What I missing now is ability to add the COUNT number to the link text. E.g DOCUMENT 1 or DOCUMENT 2.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `it also has other text which is mixed with the links.`. And, can I ask you about the detailed logic for retrieving the values of `Document 1` and `Document 2` from your sample input values? `Document ` is constant value and `1` and `2` are counter?

Comment: I would imagine using the number of ".pdf" found in the text and use that as a counter and concatenate it with Document & "Counter Value" but i think this might not be simple to do inside a formula.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,join("","<a href=""",regexreplace(Σ,"\s","%20"),""">Document ",index(countif(right(A2:Σ,3),right(Σ,3))),"</a>"))))
```

- the 3 characters `pdf` at the end of each link is taken into account for counter increment.

[image]